# Choosing different sites to view/query on Google analytics

Tags: java, string, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Here's a dilemma i've been struggling w all day yesterday and still have no idea how to go about solving the problem. Even someone pointing me in the right direction would be a lot of help at this point. So....

I've developed a Java program to query some data from a couple of websites using Google analytics and everything works fine. I have it so that all the values in the query is in strings which can be edited from a properties file. When a user has multiple sites in their analytics account, users should be able to change which site that they want to view the data for.

Right now I have it so that users have to put in the exact profile id into the properties file. For example i type in profileID=8309120 for demositeA. Rather I want to make it so that users can type in demositeA as their profileID. What would be the easiest way to go about this?

EDIT:
Here are some examples of my code to clarify the code that i have

my query

```
private static GaData executeDataQuery(Analytics analytics, String metrics, String dimensions, String startDate, String endDate, String sort, String profileID, String headers) throws IOException {
    return analytics.data().ga().get("ga:" + profileID, // Table Id. ga: + profile id.
        startDate, // Start date.
        endDate, // End date.
        metrics) // Metrics.
        .setDimensions(dimensions)
        .setSort(sort)
        .setMaxResults(100)
        .execute();
  }
```

I have a string that is..

```
String profileID = metricValues.profileID();
```

Comment: Log them into your app with their GA account wouldn't be an option? So you could query their granted profiles and they could choose among them.

Comment: hmmm can you clarify what you mean or give me an example? I am still really new to java and programming. I put some examples of my code up if that helps at all

Comment: demositeA Being the name of the Profile they would like to request from? Basically you want to give them the option to type the name of the view instead of the profile id?